# If statement for checking strings

Tags: delphi

So I'm trying to determine if two different strings are the same with

```
 if DerobModel.ConstructionCount > 22 then
 begin
   for i := 22 to DerobModel.ConstructionCount-1 do
   begin
     ConstructionName[i] := DerobModel.Constructions[i].Name;
     ShowMessage(ConstructionName[i]);
     ShowMessage(DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall']);
     if ConstructionName[i]=DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall'] then
     begin
       ShowMessage('Hej');
       igSurf[0]:=idWallCon[i];
     end;
     LayerCount[i] := DerobModel.Constructions[i].LayerCount;
     idWallCon[i] := i+1;
   end;
 end;
```

The ShowMessage for both of the strings returns the same string but somehow it won't go in the if statement. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, then clearly `ConstructionName[i]` and `DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall']` are not the same string. Since you've not shown us what either of them are, it's pretty difficult to diagnose what's different, but certainly it should be easy to figure out using the debugger.

Comment: @KenWhite As you can se `ConstructionName[i]` gets it name from `DerobModel.Constructions[i].Name`. This name is also in a combobox where I get the `DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall']` with `DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall']:=NWallComboBox.Items.GetText;`

How do you suggest I use the debugger? I put a breakpoint there but it just steps over it. Both of the messages that are shown display the same string, i.e. 'BetongVägg'

Comment: I can't see anything except what I wrote before, because you've not provided any of the actual values. Please read again what I wrote (and what David wrote in his answer, which is the same thing I've said). If the `=` is not finding a match, the strings are not the same. **Use the debugger** and examine them both at runtime to see what's different; I assure you they *are* in fact different.

Comment: I'm running the debugger, but I can't see how I would compare the strings in runtime besides showing them as messages and this shows me the same message. Which values do you want? The stringvalues are 'BetongVägg' for both of the messages.

Comment: I find it extremely hard to believe that the `=` operator doesn't work, it's the most common fundamental of programming.

Comment: Effective debugging is probably at least 50% observation.  It shouldn't have taken a page full of comments and answers before noticing that the strings are of different lengths, especially as it's so easy to get this info from the debugger.  That aside, it's not a bad idea to get into the habit of surrounding a string value with > and < when displaying it for debugging (even in the IDE's watch window).

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code at the `if` statement, and hover the mouse over the two values, or use the `Evaluate/Modify` window (from the Run menu or Ctrl+F7) to compare the values. If the `if` is not being entered, the strings are definitely not the same. (I've been working in Delphi since Delphi 1, and the `=` equality operator for strings has **never** failed to be correct.

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite I'm now seeing that the difference in the strings are that the `DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall']` string contains "#$D#$A" as well. By looking online it seems as if people that gets the string from a ComboBox is having this problem. Is it safe to assume that it will always be like this so I can use StringReplace for the strings?

Answer (score 2):

The `=` operator for strings is known to work. When strings `s1` and `s2` are equal, `s1 = s2` evaluates true. Otherwise it evaluates false. The `=` operator has been known to work correctly in all versions of Delphi.

The conclusion to draw is that if the body of your `if` does not execute, then the two strings are not equal. Now that you know that the two strings are not equal, you can debug the program to work out why two things that you believed to be equal are in fact not equal.

Note that equality testing with `=` is exact. Letter case is significant. Whitespace is significant. And so on.

Comment: Both of the strings get their values from the same source, just differently. As I commented above to KenWhite, both of the ShowMessage commands gives the same result which is why I can't understand why it wouldn't execute the `if`

Comment: I won't repeat what Ken said, and what I wrote in my answer. If you cannot accept it, you'll need to submit a QC report with your SSCCE.

Comment: I'm not trying to say you're wrong, but I can't understand how the stings wouldn't be equal as when I look at them in the messagebox they're the same, capitalization and everything. Also I don't understand what the debugger could do for me. I.e. when using MatLAB I could just type the variable and get the value but I can't find a way to do it for Delphi.

Comment: `ShowMessage` won't show you any possible white space, if any. The debugger is designed with very extensive tools to help you, please learn how to use it.

Comment: The strings are different. Look at the underlying bytes. Use the debugger.

Comment: Could you please point me to some guide for using the debugger properly? Don't really know what to look for and where. Sorry but I can't find anything in the debugger to look for.

Comment: Look at the underlying bytes. Print them out. Start with, for instance, `TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)` as a way to get a byte array that defines your string. Compare the two byte arrays. Or iterate through the strings printing `ord(s[i])`.

Comment: @user3464658, you should do `Evaluate/Modify` for your strings in the debugger. Actually, you should read the whole debugging tutorial because Delphi is substantially lower level than MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings are different, simple as that.
If you want to figure out what exactly is different, you could write an **else** block portion to compare the strings in detail and show you exactly what is different.

```
if ConstructionName[i]=DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall'] then
begin
  ShowMessage('Hej');
  igSurf[0]:=idWallCon[i];
end
else
begin
  if (Length(ConstructionName[i]) <> 
      Length(DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall'])) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Length('+IntToStr(Length(ConstructionName[i]))+') <> Length('+
                IntToStr(Length(DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall']))+')');
  end
  else
  begin
    for LCharPos := 1 to Length(ConstructionName[i]) do
    begin
      if (ConstructionName[i][LCharPos] <> 
          DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall'][LCharPos]) then
      begin
        //Here you might need to rather show the ordinal values of the 
        //characters to see the difference if they **look** the same due 
        //to the font of the message.
        ShowMessage('Pos['+IntToStr(LCharPos)+'] "'+
                    ConstructionName[i][LCharPos]+'" <> "'+
                    DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall'][LCharPos]+'"');
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The only thing I can think of that might unexpectedly cause "same" strings to be reported as different is: if they are different string types. E.g. if one is WideString and the other AnsiString, then:

- There would have to be an implicit conversion to do the comparison.
- And this means one of the strings would be changed.
- The change could cause two strings that *look* the same to actually be different.

Comment: Thank you! Now it seems as if the `DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall']` is 2 charachters longer. Do you reckon it could do with `DerobModel.HouseProperties.StringValue['NWall']:=NWallComboBox.Items.GetText`?

Comment: @user3464658 I doubt it. In my experience, `GetText` has always returned the exact same values I've assigned. If you've set the string values at design time, double-check that you aren't sitting with extra spaces in each line.

Comment: 2 characters longer - Then find out which two characters.

Comment: This code would be much simpler if you put it in a function which received two string parameters, s1, s2.

Comment: @David I specifically chose not to use a function because I don't know the types used in OP's code. (I don't even know if he's using >= D2009) A function could result in implicit conversion of one or both strings and adversely affect the exercise.